# How to fill the outside region of ROI with specific color?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, roi

In the below image I want to make the region outside the rectangles as black color, so how it can be done using opencv ?[image with roi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHbbT.png)

Comment: You do not make the region outside the roi black, you create a black image of the same size and then copy the roi into it.

Comment: What are the coordinates of your ROI? Are the red lines and text part of the input image or a result of your processing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes the red lines are my coordinates. And I don't want create a black image, is there any method to do this in same image..Like assigning (0,0,0) to all the pixels except that inside the red rectagles?

Comment: (0,0,0) is black and you just said you don't want black. What is your ROI?